# Positioning a text regarding to its graphical center

Tags: text, matplotlib, positioning

I would like to place a text in the center of square in such a way that the final result is really at the center.

I know that there is the method [text](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) but it does not seem to place the text regarding its graphical center.

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: In the function `text`, the coordinates `(x,y)` seems to be the ones of the left down corner of the "virtual box" containing the text. What I'm looking for is a way to have to give the coordinates of the center of "virtual box".

Comment: I will test this this weekend, just come back the next week to see if your proposition does exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can align the bounding box of a text with respect to the given coordinates with the keywors `horizontalalignment` and `verticalalignment` ([see `Text` documentations](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text)).

The options are:

```
horizontalalignment = [ 'center' | 'right' | 'left' ]
verticalalignment = [ 'center' | 'top' | 'bottom' | 'baseline' ]
```